# How can I add letters on cube?

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

It should look like the image shown here:[image: cube with letters]

I tried adding text but that is not so clean.The image shown above has a texture.

How can I add a texture such that I have letters on the faces of cube?
What should I do to add different letters on each of the faces of the cube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new window and change it to UV/Image editor
In the 3D view go to edit mode and select the face u want fix the texture and press U and select Unwrap
Go to the Properties panel next to material there is texture layout
Below in type change to image or movie
And in the Image open the image as shown in .gif
Now in the UV Editor Select the image u want to focus from drop down.
And in the 3D change from solid to texture.[image]

[image]

Comment: why are the textures not displayed in blender game engine...when I press P I only see materials added not the texture!

Comment: beside edit and object mode change the display from solid to texture

Answer (score 0):

This is the most easy way I think, just create a cube, tick Generate UVs (so you can texture it immediately), assign a material with a texture. Then you can paint the letters into the texture or import your own:

[image]
If you don't know what UV mapping is and want to understand this procedure properly, I suggest you to watch some UV Mapping and UV Unwrapping tutorials, for example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tovu1A0LxeQ

Or take a look into official Blender manual:
https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping/introduction.html

Comment: why are the textures not displayed in blender game engine...when I press P I only see materials added not the texture!